# Select record from table where last from related table is equal x in Yii2

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

How can I build query in search model to select values from `table_a` where related `table_b` last inserted record is equal to something.

My tables looks something like that

**table_a**

- id
- name
- user_id

**table_b**

- id
- table_a_id
- status
- some_other_status
- timestamp

At this moment my query in search model looks like that:

```
TableA::find()->joinWith(['user', 'TableB'])->groupBy(['table_a.id', 'table_b.table_a_id']);
```

Query generated by ActiveRecord have to give same results like query

```
SELECT a.* FROM table_a OUTER LEFT JOIN (SELECT status, some_other_status FROM table_b ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 1) as b ON b.table_a_id = a.id WHERE b.status = X;
```

Comment: Try  $query->orderBy("some_primary_id DESC");

Comment: This one will not help :( it will still search in all related items and only shows last one